# Grails table not found error on SQL 2008 legacy table

Tags: sql, grails, legacy

I'm trying to link a new Grails project to a pre-existing SQL server 2008 database, trouble is when I try to list/update or anything nothing works and I get an error reading

> Table "TEST_EXEC_QUEUE" not found; SQL statement: select top 10 this_.id as id0_0_, this_.Env as Env0_0_, this_.Priority as Priority0_0_, this_.State as State0_0_, this_.subSystem as subSystem0_0_, this_.system as system0_0_, this_.test_scenario_id as test7_0_0_ from test_exec_queue this_ [42102-164]

My datasource.groovy file is: -

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
    }

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}


// environment specific settings
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://UKSQL08;databaseName=Selenium"
        }
    }
```

and the domain file is as follows, anyone got any ideas...?

```
package testexecqueue

class TestExecQueueCheck {

    static constraints = {
        test_scenario_id(blank:false)
        myPriority()
        myState()
        myEnv()
        system()
        subSystem()
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "test_exec_queue"
        version false
        columns{

            test_scenario_id column:"test_scenario_id"
            myPriority column:"Priority"
            myState column:"State"
            myEnv column:"Env"
            system column:"system"
            subSystem column:"subSystem"
        }
    }

    Integer test_scenario_id
    Integer myPriority
    String myState
    String myEnv
    String system
    String subSystem
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be not the answer but I found that once I specified an actual account and moved back to a JDBC connection the problem went away, so its something to do with windows service accounts/JTDS  which I've yet to investigate further...  My DataSource using sqljdbc4 is now as follows and works fine...

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}


// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = 'update' // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=TestDB"
    //      databaseName = "..."
        username = "test"
        password = "test"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            //logSql = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also to add to this, if you want to use windows authentication you need to make sure you put both the jdbc jar AND the auth dll in the lib, I was getting issues with just putting the jar file in the lib folder and it wasn't until I added the auth dll as well that it started working, now means I dont need to specify a user account or password.

Answer (score 0):

There's no id in your TestExecQueueCheck domain. Rename the field `test_scenario_id` to just `id`. It should solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm that doesnt appear to make a difference, I've changed all the variables called test_scenario_id to id, have cleaned and recompiled etc then re-run and I still get the same issue...  I assume you dont mean change the database field to id do you?

Comment: I mean just the Grails domain. My suggestion should change the result: even in your SQL statement we can see that it includes an implicit column `id` (besides `test_scenario_id`). Grails always adds such column automatically. After renaming the column check the new "not found" error message. Does it include the non-existent column?

Comment: Now says   `select top 10 this_.test_exec_queue_id as test1_0_0_, this_.Env as Env0_0_, this_.Priority as Priority0_0_, this_.State as State0_0_, this_.subSystem as subSystem0_0_, this_.system as system0_0_, this_.test_scenario_id as test7_0_0_ from test_exec_queue this_ [42102-164]`

Comment: It now reads as follows  `package testexecqueue

class TestExecQueueCheck {

 static constraints = {
 
  testscenarioid()
  myPriority()
  myState()
  myEnv()
  system()
  subSystem()
 }
 
 static mapping = {
  table "test_exec_queue"
  version false
  columns{
   
   id column:"test_exec_queue_id"
   testscenarioid column:"test_scenario_id"
   myPriority column:"Priority"
   myState column:"State"
   myEnv column:"Env"
   system column:"system"
   subSystem column:"subSystem"
  }
 }
 
 Integer testscenarioid
 Integer myPriority
 String myState
 String myEnv
 String system
 String subSystem
}`

Comment: Ok, if it's possible to re-generate tables, try to change `dbCreate` to `"create"` (and restart the app) and compare the generated table schema to the original one. If they differ, maybe it's the reason and you'll have to make it coincide by some other change to the domain.

Comment: Well that potentially highlights a bigger issue, when I try this I still get an issue stating the same thing, I tried creating a new table (test_exec_queue_2) to compare the two but it looks like its not even connecting to SQL in the first place (hence the no table found message I guess) anyone any ideas on how to check the connection is valid other than running SQL queries?

Comment: If your connection url and driverClassName are correct, the connections should work. Those parameters don't depend on Grails. So, you can experiment with them (to find correct values) outside of your project, say just in a Groovy script. Use the standard JDBC commands (see your driver docs and examples), e.g. Class.forName(...) etc.